# Remove one image from array per click

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, append

I want to remove one image from the array every time someone clicks the remove button. I tried using the `splice` method but I couldn't get it to work because the image still appear to be visible after I click the remove button.

**HTML:**

```
<span>Image:</span>
<div id="image"></div>
<a class="remove" href="">Remove</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        image[i] = new Image();
        image[i].src = 'http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120809232434/fantendo/images/3/37/NSMBWii1upMushroom.png';
        $("#image").append($("<a>", {
            html: $("<img>", {
                src: image[i].src,
                height: 50
            })
        }));
    }

    $(".remove").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        image.splice(-1, 1);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa183k4/3)**

Comment: define `doesn't work`...it does remove from array. You have no code to remove from DOM though. What is purpose of the array?

Comment: What I meant by it doesn't work is that the images still appear to be visible. How can I get one image from the array to be removed every time a user clicks the remove button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is grab the index based on the length after array modification and remove it:

```
$(".remove").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    image.splice(0, 1);
    $('#image a').eq(image.length).remove();
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucyp0qoc/)

Comment: will this work with different images currently OP is using same image in array

Comment: @EhsanSajjad If you're asking if it will remove the exact same image from the DOM that you spliced, no.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad True, and although the OP didn't specify that was a requisite, here's a mockup that could be used to remove the proper elements. [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5bvxfuyt/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to append images in the container with the updated array, create a function and call it every time after removing item from array :

```
function RefreshImages(images) {
        $("#image").empty()
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = 'http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120809232434/fantendo/images/3/37/NSMBWii1upMushroom.png';

            $("#image").append($("<a>", {
                html: $("<img>", {
                    src: images[i].src,
                    height: 50
                })
            }));
        }
    }
```

and in remove event call it this way:

```
$(".remove").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    image.splice(-1, 1);

    RefreshImages(image)
});
```

### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa183k4/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Can use the `last()` method to filter the children and use `remove()` to remove from DOM

```
 $(".remove").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    image.splice(-1, 1);
    $("#image").children().last().remove();
});
```

Comment: `splice(-1,1)` will remove last item of array?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes it will, try it